# IIS bindings keep being removed

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm having a problem where the security certificate for a site is being periodically unbound from port 443 and replaced with another certificate which is sitting on the server. So whenever a user tries to access the site they are met with a 'untrusted' warning.

So when this first happened, I investigated and found the wrong certificate in place so I changed it back. This worked fine for a while but then it happened again. I checked the event logs and the following two warnings are fired:

**SSL Certificate Settings deleted for endpoint : 0.0.0.0:443**

**SSL Certificate Settings created by an admin process for endpoint : 0.0.0.0:443**

This happens once or twice a day, and I have to keep rebinding the correct certificate, and I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

The site is running on Windows Server 2012/ IIS 8

According to a couple of online support forums/articles there was an old legacy setting in the ApplicationHost.config file which was supposed to cause this. All references to this that I found referred to a property in the 'customMetaData' section, the property had a specific Id (5506). I couldn't find this specific property anywhere in our ApplicationHost.config file on the server.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Or can anyone shed any light on potential causes of this? Having looked around online I'm finding it hard to find much related to my problem, but perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing...

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:

Have since realised that this happens at 13:00 each day, cant see any significant events that are occurring on the server that might trigger it though...

Comment: I am experiencing this as well on one of my web servers. Like you I checked my ApplicationHost.config and that did not resolve the issue. I notice a small pattern that if I rebind the certificate and navigate to a URL such as https://whydoesthisbreak.com/thisisgoingtobreak.rem or https://weburl.com/thisisgoingtobreak.soap and refresh each of them a few times, the certificate unbinds. This pattern was discovered because every Saturday morning at 7am IT Security runs some tests, one of which hits a nonexistent .rem and .soap URL and breaks the web site. I'm still looking for a solution as well.

Comment: Hi, did anybody find a solution to this? I'm getting this randomly (or I haven't yet figure out why the bindings are being removed). Any help would be useful. Thanks

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I believe the issue was related to 'HIPS' in the anti-virus software we had installed on the server. The anti-virus software was ESET I think.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution
Locate the following property in the  section of the applicationHost.config file, and delete it:

```
 <property id="5506" dataType="Binary" userType="1" attributes="None" value="oXiHOzFAMOF0YxIuI7soWvDFEzg=" />
```

This property is a legacy feature from Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 and is no longer needed.

[Link to MS Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2025598/https-connections-fail-and-ssl-bindings-are-deleted-for-a-website-in-i)

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer (property id) doesn't work, follow these steps:

- Check if there is an antivirus software in the server. Look for especially HIPS feature. Disable the antivirus and try to reproduce the issue
- Check if the site is using a wildcard certificate. This issue occurs when the wildcard certificate has been imported without marking the keys as exportable. In order to solve it, the affected certificate should be uninstalled and it should be imported back again with marking the keys as exportable
- Look for System Center Virtual Machine Manager Agent in the server. If it is enabled in the server, disable it and try to reproduce the issue ([Reference](https://forums-iis.azureedge.net/t/1238859.aspx))
- Another process might be using 443 port in the server (Example: Windows Admin Center. Check this post out: [503 Service Unavailable error related to Windows Admin Center](https://port135.com/2019/05/16/solved-503-service-unavailable-windows-admin-center/))
- Check if insecure protocols are enabled. Registry settings are below. Disable these protocols if they are enabled and try to reproduce the issue

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL
>   2.0\Server HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL
>   3.0\Client HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL
>   3.0\Server HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.0\Client

Source: [SSL Certificate Settings deleted for endpoint (Event ID 15300)](https://port135.com/2020/06/11/ssl-certificate-settings-deleted-for-endpoint/)